# PHP HTML MYSQL trying to update specific row of database after user enters registration details

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am designing a website where beekeepers can register there shop details to a website and after they have registered their info to the database, they are logged in then redirected to the account management page where they can change their details if they want.

I am having a problem where after the user has entered there details, the website is directed to the register script which adds the user and their details to the database, it then takes them to a login script to log them in via the entry to the database that was just added. However it just gets stuck on the registerlogin script (yet still adds the new user). It adds them, but does not log them in after.

I have them able to log in via a log in page, which directs them to the account management page fine after a successful login, I have used similar code from the login script in the registerlogin script.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong?

**register page(user side):**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Beekeeper</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Nigel Kennington">
    <meta name="description" content="Find local honey near you">
    <meta name="keywords" content="honey, bees, bee, local">
    <link href="bees.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="linkbar">
        <table height="140px" ID="Table1">
            <tr>
                <td valign="bottom"><a href="index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</td>
                <td valign="bottom"><a href="about.html">About</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</td>
                <td valign="bottom"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="bulk">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" ID="Table1">
            <tr id="spacer">
                <td class="leftnav" align="right" valign="top" nowrap width="120px">
                    <h5>Find Honey from:</h5>
                    <p><a href="#">Highlands and Islands</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">North Eastern Scotland</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">Eastern Scotland</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">South Western Scotland</a>
                    <h5>List your produce:</h5>
                    <p><a href="keeperlogin.php">Keepers Page</a></p>
                    <p>Register</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p class="first">To get a free account and start advertising your produce here, fill in the information below:</p>
                    <p>If you already have an account, you can login by clicking on the "Keepers Page" link on the left hand side.</p>



                    <fieldset>
                    <?php
                        $fullUrl = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

                        if (strpos($fullUrl, "signup=empty") == true)
                        {
                            echo "<p class='error' >You did not fill in all fields, 
                                                    please check you have filled all fields out!</p>";
                            //exit();
                        }
                        elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "signup=passwordnotmatch") == true)
                        {
                            echo "<p class='error'>Passwords entered do not match!</p>";
                            //exit();
                        }
                        elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "signup=bothnumbersnotentered") == true)
                        {
                            echo "<p class='error'>You must enter at least one phone number!</p>";
                            //exit();
                        }
                        elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "signup=usertaken") == true)
                        {
                            echo "<p class='error'>User is already on the system!</p>";
                            //exit();
                        }
                        elseif (strpos($fullUrl, "signup=success") == true)
                        {
                            echo "<p class='success'>You have been signed up!</p>";
                            //exit();
                        }
                    ?>
                    <form method="POST" action="register.php">
                        <table border=0 id="flush">
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><div class="heading">About You</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Your Name:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="keepername" size="32"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Password:</td>
                                <td><input type="password" name="password" size="16"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Re-enter Password:</td>
                                <td><input type="password" name="password2" size="16"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Your E-mail:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="accountemail" size="32"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td colspan="2"><div class="heading">About your produce</div></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Shop Name:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="shopname" size="32"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Area:</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="radio" name="area" value="HaI"> Highlands and Islands<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="area" value="NES"> North Eastern Scotland<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="area" value="ES"> Eastern Scotland<br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="area" value="SWS"> South Western Scotland
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Address:</td>
                                <td><textarea rows="2" name="address" cols="27"></textarea></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Town/City:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="town" size="32"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Postcode:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="postcode" size="32"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Phone Number:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="landline" size="32"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Mobile Number:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="mobile" size="32"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Shop E-mail:</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="shopemail" size="32"></td>
                            </tr> 
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td>Describe your produce:</td>
                                <td><textarea rows="4" name="description" cols="27"></textarea></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="50"></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
                            </tr> 
                        </table>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td valign="top" align="right">
                    <img src="gfx/register.jpg" alt="honey pots" class="imgborder">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        © 2008 beekeeper.com | <A href="privacy.html">Privacy Policy</A> | 
        <A href="terms.html">Terms of Use</A>
    </div>

</body>
```

**register script(server side):**

```
<?php

session_start();

/* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysqli_error($db));
mysqli_select_db($link, "keepers")
or die(mysqli_error($link));

// Check connection
if($link === false)
{
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Escape user inputs for security
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['keepername']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['password']);
  $password2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['password2']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['accountemail']);
  $shop = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['shopname']);
  $area = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['area']);
  $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['address']);
  $town = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['town']);
  $postcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['postcode']);
  $landline = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['landline']);
  $mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['mobile']);
  $shopemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['shopemail']);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['description']);


   //Error Handlers
   //Check for empty fields
   if (empty($name) || empty($password) || empty($email) || empty($shop) || 
   empty($area) || empty($address) || empty($town) || empty($postcode) || 
   empty($shopemail) || empty($description)) 
   {
       header("Location: keeperregister.php?signup=empty");
       exit();
   }
   else
   {
            if ($password != $password2)
            {
                header("Location: keeperregister.php?signup=passwordnotmatch");
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                if (empty($landline) && empty($mobile))
                {
                    header("Location: keeperregister.php?signup=bothnumbersnotentered");
                    exit();
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM keepers WHERE keeper_email = '$email'";
                    $results = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
                    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

                        if ($resultCheck > 0)
                        {
                            header("Location: keeperregister.php?signup=usertaken");
                            exit();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
                            //Insert the user into the database
                            $sqlinsert = "INSERT INTO keepers VALUES ('NULL','$name', '$hashedPwd', '$email', '$shop', '$area' ,'$address' ,'$town' ,'$postcode' ,'$landline' ,'$mobile' ,'$shopemail', '$description')";
                                if(mysqli_query($link, $sqlinsert))
                                {
                                    header("Location: registerlogin.php?");
                                    exit();
                                } 
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sqlinsert. " . mysqli_error($link);
                                }
                        }
                }

            }
   }

  // close connection
  mysqli_close($link);
}
else
{
    header("Location: keeperregister.php");
    exit();
}
```

**registerlogin script(server side):**

```
<?php

session_start();

    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
        server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die(mysqli_error($db));
        mysqli_select_db($link, "keepers")
        or die(mysqli_error($link));

        // Check connection
        if($link === false)
        {
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['keepername']);
        //$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_REQUEST['password']);


            $sql = "SELECT * FROM keepers WHERE keeper_name = '$name'";
            $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            if ($resultCheck < 1)
            {
                header("Location: keeperlogin.php?login=error");
                exit();
            }
            else
            {
                if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                        //Log in the user here
                        $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['ID'];
                        $_SESSION['u_name'] = $row['keeper_name'];
                        $_SESSION['u_keeperemail'] = $row['keeper_email'];
                        $_SESSION['u_shopname'] = $row['shop_name'];
                        $_SESSION['u_area'] = $row['area'];
                        $_SESSION['u_address'] = $row['address'];
                        $_SESSION['u_town'] = $row['town/city'];
                        $_SESSION['u_postcode'] = $row['postcode'];
                        $_SESSION['u_landline'] = $row['phone number'];
                        $_SESSION['u_mobile'] = $row['mobile number'];
                        $_SESSION['u_shopemail'] = $row['shop_email'];
                        $_SESSION['u_produce'] = $row['produce'];
                        header("Location: accountmanagement.php?login=success");
                        exit();

                }
                else
        {
            header("Location: keeperlogin.php?login=error");
            exit();
        }


        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: After registering you can store something like `$_SESSION['isloggedin'] = true` and then redirect them to the users area using `header('Location: '.$yourURL);`

Comment: do you mean like this?

    $_SESSION['isloggedin'] = true
         if (isloggedin)
         {
          header("Location: 
    accountmanagement.php");
          exit();
         }

Comment: Is the login protocol for a beekeeper (or, more accurately, honey vendor) somehow different from any other kind of person? Why not use a standard script?

Comment: `if($_SESSION['isloggedin']) {header("Location: $url")};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On successful registration, you're not passing a `$_POST` value as needed in registerlogin.php. Rather than `$_POST` you better use `$_SESSION` instead. Changes below.

**In register.php:**

**Just above:**

```
header("Location: registerlogin.php?");
```

**Add:**

```
$_SESSION['keeper_name'] = $name;
```

**In registerlogin.php:**

**Replace:**

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

**With:**

```
isset($_SESSION['keeper_name']) AND $_SESSION['keeper_name'] != ""
```

**Replace:**

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['keepername']);
```

**With:**

```
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_SESSION['keeper_name']);
```